# Search in Vim above a line

Tags: search, vim

Is there anyway in vim to search for a word token above a certain line? For example I have a 12,000 line log file and I'm wondering if I can find a string sequence above a certain line number. The string sequence reoccurs a painful amount of times to just keep iterating through, so I would like to limit my search to above a specified line. I suppose I could just delete everything afterwards and then search, but that seems like a pain. I'm relatively new to vim so I don't have all the keywords down yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `:help search-range`.

You’d probably use `\%<l` for this. If, in your 12,000-line file, you wanted to search for the string “test” only above line 4,800, you could use

```
/\%<4800ltest
```

`\%<l` `\%>l` are used for “above” and “below” search ranges. The one above (`\%<l`) will look for matches above the specified line number; the other (`\%>l`) will look for matches below the line number.